# iphone: delegate questions (I think)

Tags: iphone, graphics, delegates, quartz-graphics

I've taken some stuff from Apple's QUartzDemo project and am trying to modify it.

I want to create a screen with a button that will then call the rest of the stuff to make the rectanlges from that demo.

I've created a UIViewController that handles my initial view.  It has a start button on it.  The start button code is:

```
- (IBAction)startButtonAct:(id)sender
{
    QuartzViewController *controller;

    NSLog(@"1");
    controller = [[QuartzViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name"];
    controller.quartzViewDelegate = [[[RectDrawing alloc] init] autorelease];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

It dies when on the line with "controller.quartzViewDelate":

```
-(id<QuartzViewDelegate>)quartzViewDelegate
{
    return quartzView.delegate;
}
```

with the error:

```
-[QuartzView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5274a0
```

I'm guessing that means that the sender id from startButtonAct isn't the right thing for quartzViewDelegate -- it requires something other than the id from a button.

But I'm completely stopped here.  I have no idea, after many hours of working, how to make this work.  The difference I can find is that QuartzDemo uses a navigationController, not a viewController, but in my reading, it seems that the navigation controller is basically used for tables, which I don't have.

Okay, I'm very new to this stuff, but Objective C and iPhone programming, and ObjC sometimes gives me fits, but I've traced this through and don't have any more ideas.

Help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error.  Some code in the wrong place... nothing that could help anyone else.